# Is there a way to convert some specific column to numeric?

Tags: r

I don't want to convert all my entire dataset

```
variable <- mutate_all(dataset, function(x) as.numeric(x))
```

as it gives a different dataset altogether. Can somebody help on what to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `type.convert` based on automatically checking the type of columns and converting it to `numeric`

```
 dataset <- type.convert(dataset, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or use `mutate_at`, where we specify the columns of interest wrapped in `vars`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset <- dataset %>%
     mutate_at(vars(Time, Length), as.numeric)
```

Comment: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "quosures"                     
 The second method is giving the error above

Comment: @Researchman please check your dplyr version as it should work fine

Comment: pacman::p_load(pacman, caret, tidyr, ggplot2, depthTools, depth, DDoutlier, tidyverse, spatstat, philentropy, Metrics, OutlierDetection, dplyr)
                                                                                                                                     > Mydata <- NData %% mutate_at(vars(Time, Length), as.numeric)
                                                                                                                               
  Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "quosures"

Comment: @Researchman  You can check this `data(mtcars); mtcarsnew <- as_tibble(mtcars); mtcarsnew %>% mutate_at(vars(vs, cyl),  factor)` as this works fine for me